# Installing multiple MSI's, pros & cons between WIX Bundle vs VBScript

Tags: c#, vbscript, wix, bundle, wix3.5

We have around 4-5 vendor MSI's which we need to install on our servers (we are talking about close to 50k machines ). During install there are bunch of properties which we need to pass on based on the machine on which it is running.

I had put together a WIX Bundle package which reads the properties which it needs from the Registry and for the writing the Registry values I created a C# console application. So the final output for deployment would be 3 files (console app, console app.config, wix_bundle.exe). I didnt create any custom bootstrapper for this and am just using the default bootstrapper for this application.

Now another group dealing with the same 6MSI's have come up with a VBScript to do the installation of the Vendor Msi's. They have also written logic to manage the upgrade/patches etc. We need to make a decision to go forward and I would like to know the pros and cons about this. I will mention what I think and please add to this or correct me if am wrong.

AM not for or against any solution, but I need to make sure that the solution can be sustained for years to come. We will be using this for another 5-10 years atleast.

Any help is much appreciated!

Pros of WIX Bundle
1. All the MSI's are grouped together as a single entity, so the uninstallation is very easy compared to the VBScript.
2. We have a version associated with the WIX Bundle and dont have to find the version of the individual MSI's.
3. The console application controls writing the properties need for the WIX-Bundle, so the service account/password etc has some kind of abstraction.

Cons of WIX BUndle
1. I dont how exactly its going to deal with the patches and upgrades. I see lot of posts which are saying they see issues with patches/upgrades in wix bundle.
2. Reading the arguments through the registry is not the best of the solution. It would have been better if I could pass on the properties as command line to the WIX bundle. I understand that I will have to write a custom bootstrapper for this?
3.

Pros of VBScript
1. Atleast in our case, the solution with VBScript works and there is no need for additional work.
2.

Cons of VbScript
1. During installation we use multiple service accounts, these service accounts change based on the machine, but in the VB script all these accounts (based on each machine) as well as the password is hardcoded. 
2. Maintainign the script, since it has logic for uninstallation/upgrade/patchin etc which uses the GUID/version number etc. We need to handhold/update the vbscript for each of the release to make sure that it works fine.

Comment: Would you ever be upgrading a single MSI from the bundle in the future, or are they all updated together?

Comment: yes that is a possibility, we could get a single MSI that needs to be upgraded as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use Burn. It creates an "identity" around all the required packages that you can identify, upgrade, add-on, patch, etc. Burn handles upgrades and patches of packages, Visual Studio 2012 is using it for all of their products, patches and VS Updates. If there are issues, I'd expect to see bugs opened on them. :)

Also, the wixstdba allows you to specify properties via the command-line that set Burn Variables, see the [Overridable](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_variable.htm) extension attribute from the `WixBalExtension`. You don't need a custom BA to support that feature.

Another advantage of a Bundle, if an MSI fails, Burn will attempt to rollback to get the machine in a good state again. You can control how far the rollback goes through [RollbackBoundary](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_rollbackboundary.htm) elements.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will try setting the Burn variables from the command line and also check the Rollback functionality. I will let you know if I have questions. I am not marking this as the answer yet as I am hoping to hear some other perspectives too.